# Rails sort by association count and associated field on same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Department` model with two associations to User such that

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :members, class_name:"User", foreign_key:"department_id"
   belongs_to :director, class_name:"User", foreign_key:"director_id
end
```

To display this model in a listing, sorted by number of members I can do this

```
@departments = Department.select("departments.*, COUNT(users.id) AS members").joins(:members).group("departments.id")
@departments = @departments.order("members ASC")
```

If I wanted to sort by a field (`last_name`) in the director's associated model, I could do this:

```
@departments = Department.includes(:director)
@departments = @departments.order("users.last_name")
```

However, I can't combine these two queries into one that allows correct sorting of both. If I do

```
Department.select("departments.*, COUNT(users.id) AS members").joins(:members, :director).group("departments.id, users.last_name")
```

then I get a vast ammount of duplicate results, and I also exclude resuls where `director_id` is nil. How can I structure the query so that I can order by both `COUNT(users.id)` and essentially `director.last_name` ?

**Edit**: This is the `.to_sql` for that bad combined query:

```
SELECT departments.*, COUNT(users.id) AS members FROM "departments" 
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."department_id" = "departments"."id" 
INNER JOIN "users" "directors_departments"    
ON "directors_departments"."id" = "departments"."director_id" 
GROUP BY departments.id, users.last_name 
ORDER BY users.last_name DESC
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL that rails is using for this query?  Use `.to_sql` to get the raw generated SQL.  Table aliasing is the likely culprit here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are 2 problems here:

1. You are using `.joins` on a `belongs_to` association that may not exist.
2. You are joining the same user table twice (for 2 different associations), causing rails to generate a table alias so that the SQL will be valid.  But you aren't grouping on this alias.

Solution:

You'll need a LEFT JOIN which unfortunately isn't as pretty as a standard join.  You'll also need to modify your `.group` clause:

```
Department.
  select("departments.*, COUNT(users.id) AS members").
  joins(:members, "LEFT JOIN users directors ON departments.director_id = directors.id").
  group("departments.id, directors.last_name").
  order("members, directors.last_name")
```